# Google places country code and google search

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I'm currently using Google places to fill in address forms and searching with Google api too. The problem I'm facing is conflicting data for example

`var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  postal_town: 'long_name',
  country: 'short_name',
  administrative_area_level_2: 'short_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};`

This will give me the country code GB rather than UK, when I use:

```
function initialize() {
  var options = {
   types: ['geocode']
  };

  var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

It searches for UK rather than GB, is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution seems to be look for the string you want to change and replace it with what you want via some additional code